# Ruby on Rails: How to validate data using Rspec or cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, rspec-rails

I am querying data from `HotDeal` model in Homepage01 which is present in `ProductDetailController` like this

```
def Homepage01
    @hotdetail=HotDeal.where("department_id=?",1).limit(15).offset(0)
end
```

I need to test or validate the data using Rspec. How can i validate data or any mysql error in RSpec or cucumber framework.?

Comment: What do you mean by validating it? The model's validations are run in the test environment, too, and mysql errors will be thrown and shown in the console if any. Can you please elaborate what you really want to achieve?

Comment: I will make a mysql query that is HotDeal.where("department_id=?",1).limit(15).offset(0) in controller so with this result set i have to test that whether i got expected result or any errors by using Ruby on rails testing framework

Answer (score 1):

Create a hotdeal factory using [factory girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) with `department_id 1`.

Inside your `product_detail_controller_spec.rb` (which should rather be plural btw, i.e. product_details for your controller and your spec) write:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ClientsController do
  describe "GET Homepage01" do
    it "assigns the right records" do
      FactoryGirl.create(:hot_deal)
      hotdetail = HotDeal.where("department_id=?",1).limit(15).offset(0)
      get "Homepage01"
      assigns(:hotdetail).should eq(hotdetail)
    end
  end
end
```

This will make sure that your query works 1) technically and 2) as expected.

Comment: assigns(:hotdetail).should eq(hotdetail) am not getting this line can you please explain?

Comment: `assigns(hotdetail)` makes sure that your controller assigns an instance variable called `@hotdetail` and then it makes sure that it is equal to the `hotdetail`, because that's where you use your query.

Comment: I followed with your code but am getting undefined method `assigns' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xf405358>

Comment: It seems like you need to render something to be able to use the `assigns` method - do you render something after that controller method?